# fcntl()'s return value with F_GETFD flag?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, fcntl

I'm using fcntl() on file descriptor with following call :

```
Retval = select(
    MaxSocketId + 1,
    &ReadSocketSet,
    (fd_set *)NULL,
    (fd_set *)NULL,
    (struct timeval *)NULL
);

if (Retval <= 0) {
    for (lIndexFD = 3; lIndexFD < (MaxSocketId + 1); lIndexFD++) {
        if ((lFlag = fcntl(lIndexFD, F_GETFD)) < 0) {
            if (errno == 9) {
                FD_CLR(lIndexFD, &ActiveSocketSet);
            }
        }
        else
            printf(" \n In fcntl Else cond %d ", lFlag);
    }
    continue;
}
```

But my process is going in infinite loop in else condition for fcntl() . It appears that fcntl() is returning 0.

I would like to know in which condition it returns 0 and what to do to handle this situation.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

`if (Retval <= 0)` may change to `if (Retval < 0)`.

When `Retval` is zero, `select` is running ok.

When `Retval` is -1 and errno is `EBADF`, then use fcntl check fd is valid.

You watched fcntl it's always return 0, that's because:

1. Have not set fd's `FD_CLOEXEC` flags
2. `select` is not fail and fcntl not fail too, because all fd is valid.

---

`fcntl` have many kinds of `cmd`. When using `F_GETFD`, it means retrive file descriptor flags.

Check `fcntl`'s manual, there is only one flag(FD_CLOEXEC) in this type. So if not set this flag for the fd, then `F_GETFD` will return value 0.

> File descriptor flags
>
> The  following  commands manipulate the flags associated with a file descriptor.  Currently, only one such flag is defined: FD_CLOEXEC, the close-on-exec flag.  If the FD_CLOEXEC bit is 0, the file
>         descriptor will remain open across an execve(2), otherwise it will be closed.
>
> ```
>   F_GETFD (void)
>          Read the file descriptor flags; arg is ignored.
>
>   F_SETFD (int)
>          Set the file descriptor flags to the value specified by arg.
> ```

When will it not return 0?

1. When `open` one file, the flag `FD_CLOEXEC` is default disabled. You can enable it like this.

   ```
   fd = open(filepath, O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC)
   ```
2. Call `fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)` to enable flag `FD_CLOEXEC`.

Comment: can i clear that fd from fd_set if fcntl() returns <=0 ? Because after this i need to call accept() on the sock fd .so if this flag is not set , i should clear the fd ?

Comment: also , why is it disabled in this case ? because here i'm not opening any file . I call bind() followed by listen() on the sock fd and then select() to check if it's ready to accept connections.

Comment: No ,I mean when fcntl() returns value =0 for an fd,should i clear that fd from my fd_set using FD_CLR like i'm doing in case of errno=9 (EBADF) case

Comment: For `socket` function it will be the same, default `FD_CLOEXEC` is disabled.  You can make it enable like this. `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0)`,  Or in `accept4` function `accept4(fd, addr, len, SOCK_CLOEXEC)`.   Use command `man socket` and likewise to check the manual.

Comment: @arjungaur I understand it now. When `errno=9`, then you need clear it.  In your case it's not about set or get `F_CLOEXEC`, it just checks if the fd is still valid, when select is failed.

Comment: yes, initially i didn't used fcntl() but my process went in infinite loop with errno=9 ,so i handled it by clearing that bad fd via FD_CLR . But now again it goes into loop as fcntl() returns 0

Comment: @arjungaur Use `if (Retval <0)` and `fcntl` to handle select error. Use if `(Retval == 0)` handle no fd have data come in.

Comment: ok ,but will select return 0 in this case ? Because if i had specified the timeout interval it will block until that interval only and return 0 if no fd is ready. But here tmeout is NULL , man page says in this case select will block indefinitely .So select should only return >1(fd is ready) or <1 (errno being set)

Comment: @arjungaur So have the code set socket fd to nonblock? And select function may return -1 with other type errno, like `EINTR`. Is there a chance get this errno?

Comment: No , i haven't so by default it is blocking .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182769/discussion-between-arjun-gaur-and-xianggang-zeng).